# How to read or write millions of directories?

Tags: c#, directory

I have a program that will save about 3 million directory and read them or write on them but when I want to save them with `Directory.GetDirectories(SourcEDirectorY.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` it become not responding.

What should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than `Directory.GetDirectories`, call [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What's the difference? `EnumerateDirectories` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` whereas `GetDirectories` returns an array of strings: `string[]`.

So if you do this:

```
foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(...))
{
}
```

Then you end up waiting until the entire array of directory entries is read from the disk. Contrast that to `EnumerateDirectories`:

```
foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(...))
{
}
```

The first directory is returned immediately and you can process it. Each time through the loop, one more directory name is returned. So rather than building the entire array up front, which takes approximately forever, you get the directories one at a time as they're found.

This ends up being much more memory efficient because it doesn't have to build that huge array of directory entries. More importantly, it *appears* faster because you begin getting results immediately. Whether it actually is faster or slower is an open question that depends on a number of different things. If it does differ in speed, it will likely be by only a little bit one way or the other. Certainly not enough to matter if you're doing anything significant with three million directories.

Comment: can you explain how EnumerateDirectories works if you know more about it behind the scenes? I mean somehow it should already save the directory somewhere to check that Directory has been used already right? what will happen if a new directory comes in? Just curious

Comment: @Dexters: Behind the scenes, `EnumerateDirectories` calls the Windows `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` methods. As each directory is found, it is returned. There's no need for you to cache the directory names. `EnumerateDirectories` creates an enumerator that maintains state. New directories are returned in order, provided that they aren't created in a place that's already been passed up (i.e. if you've already seen all the directories in `c:\foo` and somebody creates `c:\foo\bar`, you aren't going to see it).